# Android filesystem includes

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing a native Android app, and I need access to GraphicBuffer.h (which is located in frameworks/base/include)

So I added the following to my Android.mk

```
#Android includes
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
            $(MYDROID)/frameworks/base  \
            $(MYDROID)/frameworks/base/include
```

The problem is that GraphicBuffer.h includes a bunch of other header files, and I don't want to have to add the paths to all of them in my makefile. What is the correct way to do this?

**Update**: While I would LOVE to know the correct way of doing this for the future, in this case, all that was needed was

```
#Android includes
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
            $(MYDROID)/frameworks/base/include  \
            $(MYDROID)/hardware/libhardware/include \
            $(MYDROID)/system/core/include
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) to build native application.

What you're doing is trying to include header from Android source. This is not guaranteed to work on all devices, since this is not public API.

Comment: I am using the NDK. Perhaps I should ask for a better way to solve the problem that is causing me to require GraphicBuffer.h in the first place.